# How to get company official web site URL from company name using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've tried clearbit's API. But it doesn't give me many company's website URL. Is there any other way to do it? One of the companies whose URL this API cannot find is `'Acute Leukemia French Association'`. My code is as follows:

```
response = requests.get('https://autocomplete.clearbit.com/v1/companies/suggest?query={Acute Leukemia French Association}')

Output: []
```

Comment: How is this a coding issue?

Comment: @RJAdriaansen I didn't say that. I'm looking for an api or so which will help me to get the desired output. Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Asking for recommendations for off-site resources is off-topic. Please, check [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this earlier for similar implementations. Try this: [Crunchbase API](https://rapidapi.com/crunchbase-team1-crunchbase/api/crunchbase/)

Also, check some of other related APIs [Other APIs](https://rapidapi.com/collection/company-information-apis)

Answer (score 1):

You can try fetching Crunchbase data from the following API, it has a bit of latency but is pretty accurate-
https://rapidapi.com/shake-chillies-shake-chillies-default/api/crunchbase4

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.